# Golang take input at the bottom of the screen

Tags: go

**Details:**
I'm trying to have a program which is gonna display live information on the screen by printing it but also take input from the user at the same time. The proble is that the input message gets overwritten by the information being printed out.

**Question:**
How can I show an input message and take user input at the bottom of the screen which stays there aswell as print information on top of it.
Kind of like nano text editor has a legend at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep terminal input always at bottom in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341350/how-to-keep-terminal-input-always-at-bottom-in-golang)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I saw that question but I just don't think its clear enough and I think I need a bigger push in the right direction. I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I once asked a similar question [How did the Linux operating system display and update progress bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73865926/16702058), and with help of [ANSI-escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you can customize the behavior of displaying something on screen. Hope this helps.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    escapes "github.com/snugfox/ansi-escapes"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("before running")

    chCustomers := make(chan int, 1)
    chDone := make(chan int, 1)
    go printSomething(chCustomers, chDone)
    now_pos := 1
    bottom_y_pos := 50
    for {
        now_pos++
        fmt.Print(escapes.CursorPos(0, now_pos))
        chCustomers <- 1
        <-chDone //this just pulls something of the channel and discards it
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Print(escapes.CursorPos(0, bottom_y_pos))
        fmt.Println("user input goes here")
    }
    fmt.Print("after running")

}
func printSomething(chCustomers chan int, chDone chan int) {
    for {
        <-chCustomers
        fmt.Println("Cutting hair")
        chDone <- 1
    }
}
```

here is the image when running the code
[image]